# What is the way to copy text from Windows to iOS and vice-versa?

Tags: ios, copy-paste

What is the way to copy text from Windows to iOS and vice-versa without using iTunes?

Comment: *The* way? or are you looking for an app recommendation?

Comment: If it is an app recommendation, you can use this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/share-clipboard-free/id555952100?mt=8  It does exactly what you want, I find it very valuable

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox, Box, email, email attachment, or one of the hundreds of other cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

I would just email myself the text. You could also use some sort of IM service like Skype or something. 
I wouldn't download a whole app for that reason...